# Golang 1.6 Cannot find packages in vendor folder

Tags: go

I'm on go version 1.6.2 and am trying to `go build` an application.
Several dependencies are located inside the `vendor` folder (e.g `vendor/docker/libcompose/`) but I get a `cannot find package` when trying to load them.

Here's an error message:

```
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/docker/libcompose/cli/command" in any of:
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/github.com/docker/libcompose/cli/command (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/ali/golang/src/github.com/docker/libcompose/cli/command (from $GOPATH)
```

What am I doing do wrong?

The doc says that packages put in the `vendor` folder are loaded automatically.

Comment: Is the folder you're trying to build in outside your $GOPATH? If so then go will not look in the vendor folder https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12511

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your example, the folder structure is wrong.
The package `github.com/docker/libcompose` should be in `vendor/github.com/docker/libcompose` not in `vendor/docker/libcompose`.

See more [here](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/).